# SPL + Metaplex JS SDK Cannot Mint NFT

Tags: spl-token, metaplex-js

I am trying to mint an NFT using a mixture of @solana/spl-token and @metaplex-foundation/js.

I create the mint account:

```
createMint(
    connection,
    payer,
    mintAuthority,
    freezeAuthority,
    0
  );
```

Then, try to mint the token to a token account (already exists):

```
metaplex.nfts().create(
    {
      useExistingMint: mintAddress,
      tokenOwner: ownerAddress,
      uri,
      sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
      maxSupply: 1,
      isMutable: false,
      tokenAddress, // Already exists
      updateAuthority: payer,
      mintAuthority: payer
    },
    { payer } // I do not use `metaplex.identity()`
  );
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: This program may not be used for executing instructions
```

My main thinking is the issue is related to `useExistingMint`:

> The address of the existing mint account that should be converted into an NFT. The account at this address should have the right requirements to become an NFT, e.g. its supply should contains exactly 1 token.
>
> https://metaplex-foundation.github.io/js/types/js.CreateNftInput.html

Because the mint account has a supply of `0`. However, I am not aware of any way to create a mint account with a supply of `1`, without minting a token to an account?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello @Sky020, Could you please let me know the purpose of this instructions? Why do you need to create a mint first? Why don't you use the `useNewMint` instead of the `useExistingMint`?

Comment: @DoublersKay I am creating the mint account in a different step (at a different time) to when I need the token minted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out using `solana@1.15.2` was the issue.

What I am trying to do is completely possible, after downgrading to current stable: `1.13.7`

---

What lead me to figure this out, is I was unable to use a simple Metaplex program which previously worked:

```
  const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection);
  const createResponse = await metaplex.nfts().create(
    {
      name: 'Test',
      uri: 'http://localhost:3002/meta/...',
      sellerFeeBasisPoints: 1000,
      maxSupply: 1,
      updateAuthority: payer,
      mintAuthority: payer
    },
    { payer }
  );
```